# Regarding angular mat toolbar

Tags: angular

Here is my price.component.html

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <span>This is tool bar </span>
</mat-toolbar>
```

I had import MatToolbarModule in shared.module.ts as below

```
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';

 @NgModule({
 exports: [
     MatToolbarModule,
  ]
 })
```

and import shared module within app.module.ts

```
import { SharedModule } from 'src/app/shared/shared.module';
```

The problem is mat-toolbar is not working and did not give any error. but other mat elements works finely. Can anyone help me for this.

Comment: Did you add `MatToolbarModule` in the imports array of NgModule also?

Comment: Can you tell me what actually it is showing on screen or it does not show any thing?

Comment: Please check the link [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/style-mat-toolbar?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). :-)

Answer (score 0):

import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar'

Must be Import NOT export.

@NgModule({

imports: [

```
MatButtonModule,
MatToolbarModule
```

],

link

https://material.angular.io/components/toolbar/api

hope it helps you